# Measure alternating voltage with arduino

Tags: operational-amplifier, level-shifting, arduino-uno

I'm worried about how to measure alternating voltage with Arduino because it measures voltages from 0 to 5.

Please help me with the circuit. What I want is that when:

If Vin = - 5V Vout = 0V

If Vin = 0V Vout = 2.5V

If Vin = 5V Vout =5
  [image]

Comment: Here's a way I can think about doing this (though I don't know if it's correct....) `if Vin=-5v, don't output anything, else if there is no voltage, send a 5v signal from pin 1 and then use the voltage divider circuit to step it down to 2.5v, else if Vin=5v, use pin 2 to send a 5v signal.` You can't control the amount of voltage that comes out of a pin but you can use things like the voltage divider or something to control the voltage.

Comment: Thank you king.
What I want is a circuit that does the "Shifting Signal". As I describe in the picture above on the post

Answer (score 1):

A simple voltage divider, but used backwards, would solve your problem.

[image]

[Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Ar%20864%20192%20864%20288%200%201000%0Ar%20864%20288%20864%20384%200%201000%0AR%20864%20192%20864%20160%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A172%20864%20384%20768%20384%200%206%20-5%205%20-5%200%200.5%20Voltage%0AO%20864%20288%20960%20288%201%0Ax%20783%20359%20820%20362%204%2024%20Vin%0Ax%20928%20266%20981%20269%204%2024%20Vout%0Ax%20763%20174%20843%20204%204%2024%205%5CsV%5C%5Cnsource%0A) to simulation.

If you click the link above, then move the mouse over the -5V and scroll with your mouse button. It will change the input voltage and you will see how Vout changes accordingly. Or look to the right of the screen, where it says "Voltage" and move the slider.

Important things:

- The resistors must have the same value if you want to map [-5,5] => [0,5] Volt
- The middle point is the output
- One of the resistors goes to 5 V
- The input goes to the other resistor

I've chosen 1 kΩ for both of the resistors. This is a good value as it is not too small or too big. It is "Lagom", as we say in Sweden.

Comment: Yup. The equation (for the OP as I'm sure you already know it) is \$2.5\:\text{V}+\frac{V_\text{IN}}{2}\$. (Sweden, eh? Should have guessed. My family name is *Hedvall*.)

Comment: @jonk Ah I see now that people were thinking about solving this with an op-amp, looks like I lucked out on chosen components. --- Whenever you see a surname that ends in "sson", then you can assume that the person is from Sweden. - Hedvall, sounds very Swedish, though this is the first time I've seen/heard it.

Comment: Well, if you have another voltage source available, you can do a lot *without* an opamp. The extra voltage source and resistor helps. But yeah, you kind of lucked out too. Our family moved to the US via Canada (late 1800's from Sweden to Canada.)  Check out the area of Gothenburg, perhaps?

Comment: @jonk Hmm, Interesting, Swedish heritage ;) - I suppose [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_Americans) is related. I guess I learn something every day.- I've only been in Gothenburg during transit, I've never toured the city.

Comment: Yup! That's pretty much my family, all right! Nailed the migrations, too. I'm in Oregon, now. From the midwest, prior. From Canada, prior to that.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Actually I wanted the possibility of solving this using an AmpOp, if you could still help me on the circuit, thank you.

Comment: @JoãoChigogoro Don't expect me to update my answer. You have not shown your attempt at solving it with an op-amp. You have not shown your reasoning for using an op-amp over my simple solution. - I deemed a solution with two resistors to be barely acceptable compared to what you've "tried" which is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have an input signal 'Vin' whose magnitude is 10 Volts peak-to-peak, centered on 0 VDC.

You want an output signal 'Vout' whose magnitude is 5 Volts peak-to-peak, centered on 2.5 VDC.

So you need to design some signal conditioning circuits that perform the following mathematical function:

```
Vout = Vin/2 + 2.5
```

i.e.,

```
Vin -> [Divide by 2] -> Vx -> [+2.5 VDC] -> Vout
```

The "Vin/2" division function is straightforward. You could, for example, pass Vin through a resistor voltage divider circuit to produce the intermediate voltage 'Vx' whose magnitude is 5 Volts peak-to-peak, centered on 0 Volts.

Now you need a circuit that adds +2.5 Volts to Vx so that the AC component of Vx's signal "rides" on a DC potential of 2.5 VDC instead of 0 VDC. There are various methods for adding this +2.5 VDC offset. I recommend you read Bruce Carter's application report titled ***Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds*** which is published by Texas Instruments (document #SLOA97). This report provides step-by-step instructions for designing an op amp amplifier circuit that provides both gain and a DC offset. In your case, the amplifier's input signal is Vx, the desired gain is 1 (unity), and the DC offset is 2.5 Volts.

**==EDIT==**

The input/output signal specs described by the OP are a "special case" that can indeed be solved using the resistor voltage divider method described by @HarrySvensson, without using an op amp amplifier circuit. Nevertheless, Bruce Carter's application report is still very useful for the "general cases" where the OP's particular input/output conditions are not present.

Comment: Thank you Jim.What I have is a - + 5V signal, and I need a "Shifting" circuit for 0 - 5V (as I describe in the above photo) so that I can inject this signal into the analog input of the Arduino